# Adding New Item to JComboBox Does Not Display

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox that is editable. When the user enters a new item, I want that added to the list and display it as the selected item. I am able to add it to the list but I cannot seem to make it display as the selected item. By default I display an empty string ("") which is what the user would edit to add the new item.

```
public class EventComboBoxListener implements ActionListener {

    private JComboBox<String> eventBox=null;

    public EventComboBoxListener(JComboBox<String> event_) {
        eventBox=event_;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Selected: " + eventBox.getSelectedItem());
        System.out.println(", Position: " + eventBox.getSelectedIndex());
        if (eventBox.getSelectedIndex() < 0) {
            eventBox.addItem(eventBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
            eventBox.setSelectedItem(eventBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }
    }

}
```

It doesn't make sense to me that I have to use `setSelectedItem` with the `getSelectedItem`. That it does not work is no surprise but I don't know what else to do. The newly added item shows up in the list as it should but how do I make it the selected item in the display at the same time? I can select it after but that should not be necessary.

Added MVCE:

Main

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] list= {"","A","B","C"};
    TestTableModel model=new TestTableModel(null,new String[] {"col1","col2"});
    JTable table=new JTable(model);
    JDialog dialog=new JDialog();
    JScrollPane scroller=new JScrollPane(table);
    JComboBox<String> box=new JComboBox<String>(list);
    box.setEditable(true);
    box.setSelectedIndex(0);
    box.addActionListener(new EventComboBoxListener(box));
    JTextField field=new JTextField();
    field.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75,30));
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    dialog.setSize(new Dimension(400,100));
    dialog.add(scroller);
    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(box));
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(field));
    model.insertRow(0,new Object[] {"","placeholder"});
}

}
```

TestTableModel class

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public TestTableModel(Object[][] data_,String[] columnNames_) {
    super(data_,columnNames_);

}

}
```

Comment: (1-) Post your [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: So you are saying that the listener is correct but there is something wrong elsewhere in the code. That is all I needed to know. Thanks.

Comment: I'm saying I can't provide an answer without all the information. The problem could be in the code you posted or it could be else where I don't know the context of what you are doing or what other code you may have written does. EVERY question should include an MCVE so we don't have to guess what you are really doing. Most cases while you create the MCVE you will find your problem.

Comment: Found a solution. Still waiting for an MCVE...

Comment: I am in the process of developing one. I have one but it does not fail. The difference is that the failing one is in a JTable while the one I developed is just in a JFrame. I'll update the OP when I have it.

Comment: MVCE added to OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all some comments about the MCVE (since you will be including one with every question in the future).

We expect the code so be in a single source file so we can easily copy/paste compile and test. We don't want 3 files lying around on our machine that we need clean up after testing.

Only relevant code directly related to the problem should be included. Why do you have the TestTableModel class. Are the "column names" relevant to the problem? The point is always test your MCVE using standard JDK classes when possible.

Regarding the EventComboListener class. Again, this can be added to the combo box by using and annoymouse inner class or a lambda. This keeps the code in a single class.

> The newly added item shows up in the list as it should but how do I make it the selected item in the display at the same time?

I found that playing with your MCVE the ActionListener of the combo box is invoked at different times.

So my suggestion is to add the ActionListener to the editor of the combo box. Then we know for sure the ActionListener is only invoked when you press the Enter key. Once you press the Enter key the editor is stopped and the value is saved to the model.

So the logic would be something like:

```
//box.addActionListener(new EventComboBoxListener(box));
ComboBoxEditor editor = box.getEditor();
JTextField textField = (JTextField)editor.getEditorComponent();

textField.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String item = textField.getText();
        DefaultComboBoxModel model = (DefaultComboBoxModel)box.getModel();

        if (model.getIndexOf(item) == -1)
        {
            box.addItem(item);
            box.setSelectedIndex( box.getItemCount() - 1 );
        }
    }
});
```

So the trick is to set the select index (not the selected item). But first the logic checks to make sure the item has not already been added to the combo box.

Comment: 1) My IDE does not allow me to combine classes in a single file. Unfortunately, the formatter on this site does not seem to handle pasting from my IDE very well and to combine the two files requires a lot of manual editing opening the door to errors. 2) The code you see is the current code resulting from various attempts to resolve the problem gleaned from various postings I found resolving what appear to be similar problems so it kind of evolved. 3) I added the TableModelClass to make sure my sample represents my situation. I didn't know where the problem was. 3) Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I also thought setSelectedItem and setSelectedIndex resulted in the same thing.

Comment: `I added the TableModelClass to make sure my sample represents my situation` - you still miss the point of an MCVE. We don't care about your situation. We care about the "concept" you are describing. The MCVE starts with all standard JDK classes. If it works THEN you try using your custom class. if it doesn't work, now you have isolated a difference. And you try to figure out why your custom class is causing a problem. This is basic debugging. You need to remove custom code so see what error you might have introduced.

Comment: `My IDE does not allow me to combine classes in a single file.` - you don't need to use an IDE. Spend time learning Java, not the IDE. There is no reason you can't code the ActionListener manually as I just demonstrated in my answer. It takes no effort at all, if you really want help from the people in the forum. You get what you give. There is no reason for excuses.

Comment: `I also thought setSelectedItem and setSelectedIndex resulted in the same thing` - I would agree. But there may be some timing issues since you are changing the normal flow of logic by trying to add an item and change selection within the listener. This is not normal behaviour.